# Chart.js Label color positioning in tooltip/legend

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

Designers decided to have a pretty standard doghnut chart, with some non-standard tooltip/legend though.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7M0h.png)

The text in the center was not an issue, using chart.js context to fill that text. When it comes to the legend and the tooltip though, things get messy.

For the tooltip, I tried using the title callback to put the bold text, and using the label callback I was able to create the text, but the catch here is the label color. In fact it is shaped as a square and it is under the title, and I did not find any configuration to put it to the side and/or make it bigger.

As for the legend, the only configurations I find are either to make the color "point style" or to position them elsewhere.

Is there any good way to get the desired result?

Also I am actually using ng2-charts, which I do know has some "monkey-patch" files which do stuff, but without really knwoing the internals of chart.js I cannot completly understand what it does and/or how I can edit it without changing the dependency source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--- DICLAIMER: much of the code below is pasted from chart.js with very little changes. Chart.js code is under MIT License, please refer to that License if you plan to use it ---

Found how to do it, although it's not probably the best and/or most reusable way.

For the legend, legend itself is a plugin in chart.js source code. For that reason, I simply overwritten the plugin logic as such:

```
const defaults = Chart.defaults;
const Element = Chart.Element;
const helpers = Chart.helpers;
const layouts = Chart.layouts;

const columnLegendPlugin = {
id: 'column-legend',

beforeInit: function (chart) {
    this.stash_draw = chart.legend.draw;
    chart.legend.draw = function () {
        const me = chart.legend;
        const opts = me.options;
        const labelOpts = opts.labels;
        const globalDefaults = defaults.global;
        const defaultColor = globalDefaults.defaultColor;
        const lineDefault = globalDefaults.elements.line;
        const legendHeight = me.height;
        const columnHeights = me.columnHeights;
        const legendWidth = me.width;
        const lineWidths = me.lineWidths;

        if(opts.display) {
            const ctx = me.ctx;
            const fontColor = helpers.valueOrDefault(labelOpts.fontColor, globalDefaults.defaultFontColor);
            const labelFont = helpers.options._parseFont(labelOpts);
            const fontSize = labelFont.size;
            let cursor;

            // Canvas setup
            ctx.textAlign = 'left';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = fontColor; // for strikethrough effect
            ctx.fillStyle = fontColor; // render in correct colour
            ctx.font = labelFont.string;

            const boxWidth = getBoxWidth(labelOpts, fontSize);
            const hitboxes = me.legendHitBoxes;

            // current position
            const drawLegendBox = function (x, y, legendItem) {
                if(isNaN(boxWidth) || boxWidth <= 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // Set the ctx for the box
                ctx.save();

                const lineWidth = helpers.valueOrDefault(legendItem.lineWidth, lineDefault.borderWidth);
                ctx.fillStyle = helpers.valueOrDefault(legendItem.fillStyle, defaultColor);
                ctx.lineCap = helpers.valueOrDefault(legendItem.lineCap, lineDefault.borderCapStyle);
                ctx.lineDashOffset = helpers.valueOrDefault(legendItem.lineDashOffset, lineDefault.borderDashOffset);
                ctx.lineJoin = helpers.valueOrDefault(legendItem.lineJoin, lineDefault.borderJoinStyle);
                ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
                ctx.strokeStyle = helpers.valueOrDefault(legendItem.strokeStyle, defaultColor);

                if(ctx.setLineDash) {
                    // IE 9 and 10 do not support line dash
                    ctx.setLineDash(helpers.valueOrDefault(legendItem.lineDash, lineDefault.borderDash));
                }

                if(labelOpts && labelOpts.usePointStyle) {
                    // Recalculate x and y for drawPoint() because its expecting
                    // x and y to be center of figure (instead of top left)
                    const radius = boxWidth * Math.SQRT2 / 2;
                    const centerX = x + boxWidth / 2;
                    const centerY = y + fontSize / 2;

                    // Draw pointStyle as legend symbol
                    helpers.canvas.drawPoint(ctx, legendItem.pointStyle, radius, centerX, centerY, legendItem.rotation);
                } else {
                    // Draw box as legend symbol
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, boxWidth, Math.min(fontSize, labelOpts.boxHeight));
                    if(lineWidth !== 0) {
                        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, boxWidth, Math.min(fontSize, labelOpts.boxHeight));
                    }
                }

                ctx.restore();
            };
            const fillText = function (x, y, legendItem, textWidth) {
                const halfFontSize = fontSize / 2;
                const xLeft = /* boxWidth + halfFontSize + */ x;
                //const yMiddle = y + halfFontSize;

                const yMiddle = y + labelOpts.yShift;

                if(legendItem.text && legendItem.text.length > labelOpts.maxLabelLength) {
                    legendItem.text = (legendItem.text as string).slice(0, labelOpts.maxLabelLength) + '.';
                }

                ctx.fillText(legendItem.text, xLeft, yMiddle);

                if(legendItem.hidden) {
                    // Strikethrough the text if hidden
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                    ctx.moveTo(xLeft, yMiddle);
                    ctx.lineTo(xLeft + textWidth, yMiddle);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            };

            const alignmentOffset = function (dimension, blockSize) {
                switch(opts.align) {
                    case 'start':
                        return labelOpts.padding;
                    case 'end':
                        return dimension - blockSize;
                    default: // center
                        return (dimension - blockSize + labelOpts.padding) / 2;
                }
            };

            // Horizontal
            const isHorizontal = me.isHorizontal();
            if(isHorizontal) {
                cursor = {
                    x: me.left + alignmentOffset(legendWidth, lineWidths[0]),
                    y: me.top + labelOpts.padding,
                    line: 0
                };
            } else {
                cursor = {
                    x: me.left + labelOpts.padding,
                    y: me.top + alignmentOffset(legendHeight, columnHeights[0]),
                    line: 0
                };
            }

            const itemHeight = fontSize + labelOpts.padding;
            helpers.each(me.legendItems, function (legendItem, i) {
                const textWidth = Math.min(ctx.measureText(legendItem.text).width, 100);
                const width = boxWidth + (fontSize / 2) + textWidth;
                let x = cursor.x;
                let y = cursor.y;

                // Use (me.left + me.minSize.width) and (me.top + me.minSize.height)
                // instead of me.right and me.bottom because me.width and me.height
                // may have been changed since me.minSize was calculated
                if(isHorizontal) {
                    if(i > 0 && x + width + labelOpts.padding > me.left + me.minSize.width) {
                        y = cursor.y += itemHeight;
                        cursor.line++;
                        x = cursor.x = me.left + alignmentOffset(legendWidth, lineWidths[cursor.line]);
                    }
                } else if(i > 0 && y + itemHeight > me.top + me.minSize.height) {
                    x = cursor.x = x + me.columnWidths[cursor.line] + labelOpts.padding;
                    cursor.line++;
                    y = cursor.y = me.top + alignmentOffset(legendHeight, columnHeights[cursor.line]);
                }

                drawLegendBox(x, y, legendItem);

                hitboxes[i].left = x;
                hitboxes[i].top = y;
                hitboxes[i].height = labelOpts.yShift + labelOpts.boxHeight + labelOpts.fontSize;
                hitboxes[i].width = Math.max(Math.min(ctx.measureText(legendItem.text).width, 100), boxWidth);

                // Fill the actual label
                fillText(x, y, legendItem, textWidth);

                if(isHorizontal) {
                    cursor.x += width + labelOpts.padding;
                } else {
                    cursor.y += itemHeight;
                }
            });
        }
    };
  }
};
```

This code works just fine, if you need to use the old legend simply implement a logic to reuse the stashed functions.

Tooltips are quite harder to handle though, since they are a core functionality with little to no exported API. But you could overwrite the prototype, reusing the code from chart.js:

```
const defaults = Chart.defaults;
const Element = Chart.Element;
const helpers = Chart.helpers;
const layouts = Chart.layouts;

function getAlignedX(vm, align) {
    return align === 'center'
    ? vm.x + vm.width / 2
    : align === 'right'
        ? vm.x + vm.width - vm.xPadding
        : vm.x + vm.xPadding;
}

export const niceTooltipPlugin = {
id: 'nice-tooltip-plugin',

beforeInit: function (chart) {
    Chart.Tooltip.prototype.draw = function () {
        const ctx = this._chart.ctx;
        const vm = this._view;

        if(vm.opacity === 0) {
            return;
        }

        const tooltipSize = {
            width: Math.max(vm.width, ctx.measureText(vm.body[0].lines[0].tooltipLabel).width + 50, ctx.measureText(vm.body[0].lines[0].tooltipData).width + 50),
            height: 1.5 * vm.height
        };
        const pt = {
            x: vm.x,
            y: vm.y
        };

        const opacity = vm.opacity;

        // Truthy/falsey value for empty tooltip
        const hasTooltipContent = vm.title.length || vm.beforeBody.length || vm.body.length || vm.afterBody.length || vm.footer.length;

        if(this._options.enabled && hasTooltipContent) {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.globalAlpha = opacity;

            // Draw Background
            this.drawBackground(pt, vm, ctx, tooltipSize);

            // Draw Title, Body, and Footer
            pt.y += vm.yPadding;

            // Titles
            this.drawTitle(pt, vm, ctx);

            // Body
            this.drawBody(pt, vm, ctx);

            // Footer
            this.drawFooter(pt, vm, ctx);

            ctx.restore();
        }
    };

    Chart.Tooltip.prototype.drawBody = function (pt, vm, ctx) {
        const bodyFontSize = vm.bodyFontSize;
        const bodySpacing = vm.bodySpacing;
        const bodyAlign = vm._bodyAlign;
        const body = vm.body;
        const drawColorBoxes = vm.displayColors;
        const labelColors = vm.labelColors;
        let xLinePadding = 0;
        const colorX = drawColorBoxes ? getAlignedX(vm, 'left') : 0;
        let textColor;

        ctx.textAlign = bodyAlign;
        ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
        ctx.font = helpers.fontString(bodyFontSize, vm._bodyFontStyle, vm._bodyFontFamily);

        pt.x = getAlignedX(vm, bodyAlign);

        // Before Body
        const fillLineOfText = function (line) {
            ctx.fillText(line, pt.x + xLinePadding, pt.y);
            pt.y += bodyFontSize + bodySpacing;
        };

        // Before body lines
        ctx.fillStyle = vm.bodyFontColor;
        helpers.each(vm.beforeBody, fillLineOfText);

        xLinePadding = drawColorBoxes && bodyAlign !== 'right'
            ? bodyAlign === 'center' ? (bodyFontSize / 2 + 1) : (bodyFontSize + 2)
            : 0;

        // Draw body lines now
        helpers.each(body, function (bodyItem, i) {
            textColor = vm.labelTextColors[i];
            ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
            helpers.each(bodyItem.before, fillLineOfText);

            helpers.each(bodyItem.lines, function (line) {
                // Draw Legend-like boxes if needed
                if(drawColorBoxes) {
                    /* // Fill a white rect so that colours merge nicely if the opacity is < 1
                    ctx.fillStyle = vm.legendColorBackground;
                    ctx.fillRect(colorX, pt.y, bodyFontSize, bodyFontSize);

                    // Border
                    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = labelColors[i].borderColor;
                    ctx.strokeRect(colorX, pt.y, bodyFontSize, bodyFontSize);

                    // Inner square
                    ctx.fillStyle = labelColors[i].backgroundColor;
                    ctx.fillRect(colorX + 1, pt.y + 1, bodyFontSize - 2, bodyFontSize - 2);
                    ctx.fillStyle = textColor; */
                    ctx.fillStyle = labelColors[i].backgroundColor;
                    helpers.canvas.drawPoint(ctx, undefined, 5, pt.x, pt.y + 12, 360);
                    ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
                }

                ctx.font = helpers.fontString(bodyFontSize, "bold", vm._bodyFontFamily);
                fillLineOfText(line.tooltipLabel);
                ctx.font = helpers.fontString(bodyFontSize, "normal", vm._bodyFontFamily);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#b0b0b0";
                fillLineOfText(line.tooltipData);
                ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
            });

            helpers.each(bodyItem.after, fillLineOfText);
        });
    };
 }
};
```